# Access all the trailing mail associated with email using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

How can I access all the trailing emails of a mail.?

I am using IMAP with Java Mail. When I get meesage using IMAP, I get only the original message . I dont get all trailing emails.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the entire thread of messages, to which your message is a reply?  You have to do that yourself.  [This article](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) will get you started.